# $F(x)=\int_0^x (t-2)f(t)\, dt$ with $f(0)=1$, $f(1)=0$ has an extremum in $(0,3)$?

Tags: calculus

> $\displaystyle F(x)=\int_0^x (t-2)f(t)\; dt$ with $f(0)=1$, $f(1)=0$ has an extremum in $(0,3)$?

The title explains a lot. Given
$$
\displaystyle F(x)=\int_0^x (t-2)f(t)\,dt
$$
with $f(0)=1$, $f(1)=0$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a strictly decreasing differentiable function. Then:

1) $F$ is strictly increasing in $[0,3]$
2) $F$ has a unique maximum but no minimum in $(0,3)$
3) $F$ has a unique minimum but no maximum in $(0,3)$
4) $F$ has both maximum and minimum in $(0,3)$

I have done $F''(x)=(x-2)f'(x)+f(x)$ but no idea how to verify the options. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is not difficult to compute the sign of $F'(x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$F'(x)=(x-2)f(x)$$

$f$ is strictly decreasing and differentiable (thus continuous). So $f(x) > 0$ on $[0,1)$, $f(1)=0$, and $f(x) <0$ on $(1,3]$.

$F'(x)<0$ on $[0,1)$, $F'(1) =0$, $F'(x) >0$ on $(1,2)$, $F'(2)=0$, and $F'(x)<0$ on $(2,3]$

So $1$ is the minimum point, $2$ is the maximum point. $F(x)$ first decreases, and then reaches local minimum, then increases, then reaches local maximum, and then decreases again. $F''(1) >0$ and $F''(2) < 0$ also confirms this.

Comment: Why you claim $F'(x)>0$ on $(2,3]$?   $f$ is negative for $x>1$

Comment: this is wrong...

Comment: @luka5z yes, I thought f(x)'s information was given on the whole range of [0,3] (and thus f is non negative), and it turned out the two points are given at 0, and 1, which makes things different. I've updated the answer accordingly, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

Since $F'(x) = (x-2)f(x)$, then if $F'(x) = 0$, it implies that either $x = 2$ or $f(x) = 0$. We also know that $f$ is strictly decreasing, so $f$ has at most one root. Given that $f(1) = 0$, then the only solution for $f(x) = 0$ is $x = 1$. Hence $F'(x) = 0$ implies that either $x = 1$ or $x = 2$.

Now, on $(0,3)$, we divide into three cases:

1. If $0 < x < 1$, then $x-2<0$ and $f(x) > 0$, so $F'(x) < 0$. [Note: $f(x) > 0$ since $f$ is strictly decreasing and $f(0) = 1$ and $f(1) = 0$]
2. If $1 < x < 2$, then $x-2<0$ and $f(x) < 0$, so $F'(x) > 0$.
3. If $2 < x < 3$, then $x-2>0$ and $f(x) < 0$, so $F'(x) < 0$.

Hence, $F$ cannot be possibly strictly increasing on $(0,3)$. $F$ has a minimum when $x = 1$ and maximum when $x = 2$. The only true statement is (4).